# How can I update the rows in external Hive table when ACID properties are off?

Tags: hive, pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

The transaction manager is non ACID so I cannot obviously use ACID transactional operation here. I tried using "insert Overwrite" and it is only working on managed table not on external table.

Is there a possible way to do it from Pyspark?

PS: hive table gets loaded by a job in production.There are few rows which we need to update manually. And the table is stored in AWS S3

Comment: As per my understanding, you can do insert overwrite for external tables, What error/issue are facing when trying to insert overwrite external tables

Comment: @Vijiy AWS S3 access denied